# I want to clear all data stored by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing data by jQuery data() in HTML Elemnets ....
After using that data, I want to reset that data for each & every element ...

I don't want to load page again ...

Comment: What code are you using to store the data?

Comment: What you are saying is the same as `I want to download the whole internet`. According to HTML5 specs you can associate arbitrary data in html elements using `data-` syntax, i.e. `data-action-clicked="true"` or even `data-images-list="[{&quot;Url&quot;:&quot;example.com&quot;}]"`

Comment: @Dogbert: See Users who have commented after the answer understood my problem ... If you don't understand question then don't comment ... at least don't    decrease my reputation ...

Comment: @Swapnil_go20: Don't expect good reputation with that kind of attitude when you can't even ask a question properly. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

> `jQuery.removeData( element [, name] )`
>
> **`element`**: A DOM element from which to remove data.
>
> **`name`**: A string naming the piece of data to remove.

Comment: As the docs state, it is also possible to call this function without any parameters to remove all data. " When called with the name of a key, jQuery.removeData() deletes that particular value; when called with no arguments, all values are removed."

Comment: @Niko: You said  jQuery.removeData() deletes that particular value; when called with no arguments, all values are removed." .............. . But There is nothing Like this ... It removes data for particular element but we cannot remove all data like this..

Comment: @Niko : Thanks.. for reply ... Yes it is mentioned there ... But It didn't worked for me ..